# represent binary search trees in python

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

how do i represent binary search trees in python?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to build a binary search trees for the sake of learning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
class Node(object):

  def __init__(self, payload):
    self.payload = payload
    self.left = self.right = 0

    # this concludes the "how to represent" asked in the question.  Once you
    # represent a BST tree like this, you can of course add a variety of
    # methods to modify it, "walk" over it, and so forth, such as:

  def insert(self, othernode):
    "Insert Node `othernode` under Node `self`."
    if self.payload <= othernode.payload:
      if self.left: self.left.insert(othernode)
      else: self.left = othernode
    else:
      if self.right: self.right.insert(othernode)
      else: self.right = othernode

  def inorderwalk(self):
    "Yield this Node and all under it in increasing-payload order."
    if self.left:
      for x in self.left.inorderwalk(): yield x
    yield self
    if self.right:
      for x in self.right.inorderwalk(): yield x

  def sillywalk(self):
    "Tiny, silly subset of `inorderwalk` functionality as requested."
    if self.left:
      self.left.sillywalk()
    print(self.payload)
    if self.right:
      self.right.sillywalk()
```

etc, etc -- basically like in any other language which uses references rather than pointers (such as Java, C#, etc).

**Edit**:

Of course, the very existence of `sillywalk` is silly indeed, because exactly the same functionality is a singe-liner external snippet on top of the `walk` method:

```
for x in tree.walk(): print(x.payload)
```

and with `walk` you can obtain just about any other functionality on the nodes-in-order stream, while, with `sillywalk`, you can obtain just about diddly-squat.  But, hey, the OP says `yield` is "intimidating" (I wonder how many of Python 2.6's other 30 keywords deserve such scare words in the OP's judgment?-) so I'm hoping `print` isn't!

This is all completely beyond the actual question, on **representing** BSTs: *that* question is entirely answered in the `__init__` -- a `payload` attribute to hold the node's payload, `left` and `right` attribute to hold either `None` (meaning, this node has no descendants on that side) or a `Node` (the top of the sub-tree of descendants on the appropriate side). Of course, the BST constraint is that every left descendant of each node (if any) has a payload less or equal than that of the node in question, every right one (again, if any) has a greater payload -- I added `insert` just to show how trivial it is to maintain that constraint, `walk` (and now `sillywalk`) to show how trivial it is to get all nodes in increasing order of payloads.  Again, the general idea is just identical to the way you'd *represent* a BST in any language which uses references rather than pointers, like, for example, C# and Java.

Comment: You should space this out a bit, it's quite hard to read all together like that.

Comment: @Alex Yield !!!! :| i am sure there's a less intimidating solution than this for a newbie like me.

Comment: @Bunny, Python has very few keywords indeed (31, as of 2.6) -- which ones out of this tiny number do you find "intimidating"?  Anyway, I'm going to add a completely silly and pointless walk-like method (working essentially just like `walk` but in an insanely restricted way) if that makes you happy (and add whitespace to make @detly happy too) -- editing the A accordingly.

Comment: @Bunny - don't be thinking `yield` is hard just because it's not common amongst other languages. Write maybe a couple of DIY examples and I'm sure it'll become much clearer.

Comment: @Alex: Any particular reason for using `0` instead of `None` in the __init__()?

Comment: @John, none in particular -- any "falsish" value (0, None, False) would do just as well (as I'm later testing with simple `if self.left:` etc).

Comment: If you want the convention that the left subtree is less than the parent, then the line: `if self.payload <= othernode.payload:` should be `if self.payload > othernode.payload:`